# Swift-passing global variables to the @IBAction function?

Tags: swift

I am trying to allow the user to select a .png file to open by clicking file on the menu bar of the application, and then open a Microsoft Word file in the same way.

The problem is it appears that `@IBAction func SelectFileToOpen(sender: NSMenuItem) {}` cannot access global variables, or set them, and seems completely independent from the rest of the code

here is my code designed to demonstrate how the method can't read global variables:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  Swift class based
//
//  Created by ethan sanford on 2015-01-16.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 ethan D sanford. All rights reserved.
//

import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    var myURL=NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "")

    @IBAction func btnConcat(sender: NSButton) {
        myURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "///Users/ethansanford/Desktop/BigWriting.png")
        var say_something = "set URL button clicked"
        print(say_something);

        print(myURL)
    }

    @IBAction func SelectFileToOpen(sender: NSMenuItem) {
        var say_something = "Menu bar, file-open clicked:"
        print(say_something);
        print(myURL);

    }

    @IBAction func communicate(sender: AnyObject) {
        var say_something = "communicate button clicked:"
        print(say_something);
        print(myURL);

    }
}
```

Here is the `NSlog` produced from this code. Notice that the URL button and the commincate button methods can share the myURL variable, but the file open button seems unable to:

```
URL button clickedOptional(file://///Users/ethansanford/Desktop/BigWriting.png)
communicate button clicked:Optional(file://///Users/ethansanford/Desktop/BigWriting.png)Menu bar
 file-open clicked:nil
communicate button clicked:Optional(file://///Users/ethansanford/Desktop/BigWriting.png)
```

I need the `myURL` variable to be able to be used in all three methods. This is necessary for later when I need these methods to communicates so I can take the users selection and display it in an image well. Thanks for any help you can provide. I believe the problem is something specific to the file button in the menu bar.

Can anyone explain to me how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your code `myURL` is an instance variable that will be created within the app delegate. I wonder if you have oversimplified your code sample.

Having said that it should be accessible from the instance methods of the app delegate but having IBAction methods in the AppDelegate rather than in UI code seems like an odd choice (I've never tried it).